# C# how to disable a child form of a MDI parent when a different child form is open

Tags: c#

so the title say it all kinda. I have an MDI parent that opens up a child that lets me view a data grid but this child lets me select a row and open up a different child from of the parent that lets me edit the data row. how do i disable the previous child till the current one is closed. kinda like ShowDialog() but for child forms ?

any help would be great :)

Comment: I presume you're using WinForms?

Comment: ShowDialog should still work, just make sure you pass the creating form to the new child window, i.e. `yourform.ShowDialog(this);`

Comment: What's wrong with ShowDialog?  Why does it have to be an MDI window?  Especially since you can't do anything with the other MDI windows?

Comment: yes im using winforms.  im using the MDI as it contains everything in the one place and works best for how everything is arranged.. i tried to just disable it when you open up the next child but i found no way to enable  it when the other child was closed

Comment: @Nathanials-c child-window MDI is very poor for usability. Is there a reason you can't use tabbed-documents instead? There are plenty of tabbed+docking frameworks available for WinForms that offer a much better user-experience than child-window MDI.

Comment: MDI is outdated since at least 10 years. Do you really want your application to look so obsolete and from another decade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the form when you open the new one and re-enable on the form closed event of the child form

Wherever you are opening the child form:...

```
{
   ChildForm f = new ChildForm();
   f.FormClosed += F_FormClosed;
   f.Show();
   this.Enabled = false;
}
```

and

```
private void F_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: this easily dropped in to my current code and does what i need thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
this.MdiParent.MdiChildren[0].Enabled = false;
```

Comment: i think this would work if the parent could control the child but the second child is opened only from the first child. then is told  that the parent of the first child is the new childs parent too. if that makes sense.